# Standard reference for Feynman-Kac Formula

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, finance

Is there any standard reference for the "modern" Feynman-Kac formula as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)?

By modern I don't mean the earliest version by Kac (for which the reference seems to be this work: *Kac, Mark (1949). "On Distributions of Certain Wiener Functionals". Transactions of the American Mathematical Society. 65 (1): 1–13.*), but the version which is cited in the link above or used in most Finance Textbooks when it comes to solving the Black-Scholes PDEs.

The textbooks I read just use it without any reference and a short google-search couldn't reveal any helpful documents.

I'm thankful for any hints and links to this - admittedly not very precise - question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Feynman-Kac formula is treated in pretty much every book about SDEs by now. No one should have trouble finding his/her favourite modern source about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be in any book on stochastic calculus. For example Klebner's book *Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications* has a proof on page 155, plus all the ingredients for it before. I'm sure other books like Oksendal etc. should likely have it as well. I just like Klebner's book.

If you're interested, I did my undergrad senior thesis on Feynman Kac formula which can be found here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/undergrad/research/thesis/ or my website [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~zselk/](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ezselk/)

ADDED: as of 22 July 2023 these links are dead.

Comment: Long live [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)! I am really surprised that people have so much trouble finding material about such a famous formula which is handled in every book treating SDEs. Another one: Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

Comment: Re: the dead link to Zachary Selk's thesis, the link leads to the title via the Wayback Machine, and a search on the title leads to a current link to the PDF: "Connecting Brownian Motion and Partial Differential Equations with Applications in Statistical and Quantum Mechanics," https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~webfiles/undergrad_thesis/201410_Zachary_Selk_Deckert.pdf.

Comment: See also Google Scholar for a replacement for the dead link: https://scholar.google.ca/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=p25XJPIAAAAJ&citation_for_view=p25XJPIAAAAJ:d1gkVwhDpl0C